# What are Angulars animation parameters?

Tags: angular

i am currently creating an Angular application with a sidenav and i want to add an animated toggle button to open and close the sidenav. (Compare Google Maps)
Angulars Sidenav has a built in open-close animation. Now i want my button to "follow" that animation. 
I'm implementing it by using Angular Animations. The only problem is that I had to guess the animation timing parameters so the result doesn't look really smooth.

```
    animations: [
    trigger('openClose', [
      // ...
      state('open', style({
        left: '20%'
      })),
      state('closed', style({
        left: '0%'
      })),
      transition('open => closed', [
        animate('0.1s')
      ]),
      transition('closed => open', [
        animate('0.1s')
      ]),
    ]),
  ]
```

***Is there anywhere to lookup Angulars default animation timing parameters?***

Comment: You can refer to the accepted answer of this [question](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aprhds) and implement it using Angular animations.

Comment: Pardon me, but that link isn't helpful. It refers to a non working stackblitz project and no stackoverflow thread.

Comment: The hamburger and open-close animations present in Google apps are not shared by Google through any lib or packages. But it is not difficult to implement it on your own. The thread I have shared has implemented it using CSS. Just borrow those ideas and create it using Angular animations.